# Netcat - How to listen on a TCP port using IPv6 address?

Tags: linux, netcat

I am using the newest version of netcat (`v1.10-41.1`) which does not seem to have an option for IPv6 addresses (as the `-6` was in the older versions of `nc`).

If I type in `nc -lvnp 2222` and check listening ports with `netstat -punta`, the server appears to be listening on port `2222` for IPv4 addresses only:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2222            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2839/nc
```

tcp6 is not active like, for example, my apache2 server:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There are at least 3 or 4 different implementations of netcat as seen on Debian:

- [netcat-traditional](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/netcat-traditional) 1.10-41 the original which doesn't support IPv6: probably what you installed.
- [netcat6](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/netcat6) which was made to offer IPv6 (oldstable, superseded).
- [netcat-openbsd](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/netcat-openbsd) 1.130-3 . Does support IPv6.
- [ncat](https://packages.debian.org/buster/ncat) 7.70+dfsg1-3 probably a bit newer since not in Debian stable, provided by [nmap](https://nmap.org/), does support IPv6.

I'd go for the openbsd one. Each version can have subtly different syntax, so take care.

By the way: [socat](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/socat) is a much better tool able to really do much more than netcat. You should try it!

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for suggesting the `socat` tool. It apparently has way more options, and the following: `socat tcp6-listen:2222` did the job.

Comment: @bashbin but a bit more verbose in its syntax. that would be `socat tcp6-listen:2222,reuseaddr -` (or probably `reuseport` instead) if you want to use it twice in a row when the server (the socat command) disconnects first.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the functionality of ipv4 & ipv6 is in fact a result of confusion around there being multiple implementations (forks) or completely different versions. If you search you'll stumble across mentions of `nc6`. This implementation seems to be in the BSD based distros.

I'd try installing `nc6` on your particular distro and running it instead of `nc` for ipv6 support.

#### Further research

I was able to find this [commit dated 2018-01-11- add IPv6 patch](https://sourceforge.net/p/nc110/git/ci/3807536449f82819a009556fe2594076bed5bea4/) which clearly is adding the IPv6 functionality back into what you're calling the *newer* version of netcat.

**NOTE:** I have only access to nc 7.50 on my systems and it, as you describe, supports both `-4` and `-6`.

I suspect what you think is a newer version of netcat is in fact a much older version: http://nc110.sourceforge.net/.

If you'd like an exhaustive list of the various implementations this is available in the [Wikipedia question about Netcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat).

> The original version of netcat was a Unix program. The last version (1.10) was released in March 1996.[1](https://sourceforge.net/p/nc110/git/ci/3807536449f82819a009556fe2594076bed5bea4/)

On most Linux distros either GNU netcat or the NMAP version appear to be what most are using:

> There are several implementations on [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) systems, including rewrites from scratch like [GNU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU) netcat[[5]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat#cite_note-5) or [OpenBSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenBSD) netcat,[6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenBSD) the latter of which supports IPv6 and [TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security). The OpenBSD version has been ported to the [FreeBSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD) base[7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) and Windows/Cygwin.[8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD) Mac OS X comes with netcat installed as of OSX 10.13 or users can use MacPorts to install a variant.[9] There is also a Microsoft Windows version of netcat available.[10]

For example, on CentOS 7.x:

```
$ nc --version
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )

$ rpm -qf /bin/nc
nmap-ncat-6.40-13.el7.x86_64
```