# netcat closing connection on localhost listening end after connection attempt

Tags: networking, netcat, port

Ι am nc-listening on `localhost:2500`

```
▶ nc -l 2500
_
```

On another terminal I am trying to connect to this listening end

```
▶ nc -zv localhost 2500
nc: connectx to localhost port 2500 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
Connection to localhost port 2500 [tcp/rtsserv] succeeded!
```

Why does it seem like the first attempt is failing?

I also noticed that when the connection attempt finishes (apparently succesffully) for some reason, my listening process exits. No idea why this is happenning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many different implementations of netcat.

I'll assume you are not using the traditional implementation but a more modern one, which can handle IPv6, because 1st issue looks related to IPv6. Here I'm using the OpenBSD variant of `nc` (version 1.217, on Debian 11 as 1.217-3).

- First issue: double connection

  - `nc -l 2500` listens on IPv4
  - `nc -zv localhost 2500` attempts first to connect to IPv6 localhost `::1`, fails and transparently retries as IPv4 localhost `127.0.0.1`: success

  My netcat gives more information:

  ```
  $ nc -zv localhost 2500
  nc: connect to localhost (::1) port 2500 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
  Connection to localhost (127.0.0.1) 2500 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
  ```

  You could avoid this for example by:

  - stating 127.0.0.1 on the client command instead of localhost or using the `-4` option to try only IPv4.
  - or changing the dual-stack preferences for the resolution of *localhost* to favor IPv4 over IPv6. On glibc-based systems such as most Linux this can be done by adding this in `/etc/gai.conf`:

    ```
    precedence  ::1/128       5
    ```
  - or by stating `-6` on the server command which will use IPv6. Actually, chances are the IPv6 socket will default to dual-mode IPv4+IPv6 as per [RFC 3493](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3493#section-5.3).
- second issue: server command ends

  The zero mode scan of *netcat* with TCP simply establishes a connection and ends it: zero data is transfered, but a connection was still established and closed. So the server command having done its role ends by default (that's the behavior of the OpenBSD variant. For example the original/traditional variant didn't do this but didn't use IPv6 either).

  Add the required option to the server command so it keeps a listening socket and doesn't stop at the first connection received. For the OpenBSD version this is option `-k`: "Keep inbound sockets open for multiple connects":

  ```
  nc -k -l 2500
  ```

Note that [there are other implementations](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/457670/netcat-how-to-listen-on-a-tcp-port-using-ipv6-address/457685#457685) of *netcat* and each have its own subtle difference. My advice about which to use is: none, use [`socat`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html#EXAMPLES) instead which has way more features.